# addChild() method doesn't work properly

Tags: actionscript-3, invisible, addchild

I'm trying to print some images on the stage but something goes wrong during collaudes, not all the images are printed, i traced them to verify if they exist, and they do, I verified they also have proper coordinates, and they do... You just can't see them... why?
validFaces is an array containing some bitmaps, OXA is an array containing some Points, their coordinates should be parrallel as i've done... Why sometimes some of them are invisible?

```
function printOpponents():void{
    for (var k:int = 0; k<numOpp; k++){
        addChild(validFaces[k]);
        validFaces[k].x = OXA[k].x;
        validFaces[k].y = OXA[k].y;

    }
}
```

Comment: `addChild` is a function

Comment: How large is the number `numOpp`

Comment: it corresponds to validFaces.length

Comment: Can I see *all* of your code?

Comment: can I send it in private to you?

Comment: What's your email address?

Comment: Look at my profile (axxxdmxxxinxxx@videxxxogamecheaxxxtsultra.com) - Remove the **x**'s

Comment: Why can't you post enough code to allow people to help you? It's just a guessing game at the moment.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet, oftentimes people cannot post more code because of proprietary restrictions. Being one of those people at times, I can vouch for the difficulty of balancing between posting "enough for people to help" and "too much". Thus why he offered to send it privately. That's a common compromise that can work.

Answer (score 0):

Try making them above the highest index:

```
function printOpponents():void{
    for (var k:int = 0; k<numOpp; k++){
        addChild(validFaces[k]);
        validFaces[k].x = OXA[k].x;
        validFaces[k].y = OXA[k].y;
        validFaces[k].parent.setChildIndex(validFaces[k], validFaces[k].parent.numChildren - 1);
    }
}
```

`validFaces[k].parent` gets the the parent of `validFaces[k]` and `setChildIndex` sets the level it should be (ex: one object is shown above another) `validFaces[k].parent.numChildren - 1` gets the Object at the highest index, therefore making `validFaces[k]` the Object that is on top of all others (`validFaces[numOpp - 1]` is technically on top of all others).

Comment: Yes its the same value... What could it be the problem?

Comment: A problem could be that the numOpps is set somewhere else, but it could be the length of the array changed somewhere else, so numOpps is not uptodate and your missing/trying to access nonexisting faces in the loop? Thats why we need more code.

Comment: I was thinking its a loading problem, maybe the program isn't able to load the images fastly enough, infact when numOpp is a small int, like 1,2 or 3 there are no problem, however i implemented a preloader at keyframe 1, but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @user3161756 Look at edit, try new code.  I had a error in the code :P

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2025: Il valore fornito per DisplayObject deve essere un elemento secondario del chiamante.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/setChildIndex()
 at flash.display::Stage/setChildIndex()
 at Piatto_Scena1_fla::MainTimeline/printOpponents()
 at Piatto_Scena1_fla::MainTimeline/frame46()

Comment: @user3161756 Oops, try new code, and if that doesn't work **move to chat** and I can better help you solve this.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks! can you explain me that line please?

Comment: @user3161756 `validFaces[k].parent` gets the the parent of `validFaces[k]` and `setChildIndex` sets the level it should be (ex: one object is shown above another) `validFaces[k].parent.numChildren - 1` gets the Object at the highest index.

Comment: Ohh damn! I said it works just because of some lucky collaudes... the problem still exist...
I'm getting bored of this...Even if this isn't the right way a programmer works, i was thinking to AVOID this problem, adding all the images outside the stange and let the code just position them... What you think?

Comment: @user3161756  Whenever you use `addChild()`, use `stage.addChild()` instead.  Tell me if this works.

Comment: :O Seems like it work now, but i'll not trust it this time, let me do something like 50 runs, i'll let you know soon.

Comment: Still not working... You want me to do a screen video so you can better understand the problem?

Comment: @user3161756 Yes, please, email it to me

Comment: @user3161756 Email it to videogamecheatsultra.com@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I successfully fixed the problem, there was a semantic wrong function in another frame, so the array validFaces used to contain images and numbers, i fixed it declaring a new array validFacesImages  cointaining all the images, and now it works ;) thank you.